# Systems start for slapd failed and timeout

Tags: ldap, puppet, openldap, slapd

I try to install openldap(v2.4.44) using puppet agent --test in a Centos 7 environment and received this error

```
Error: Systems start for slapd failed!
journalctl log for slapd:
systemd[1]: Starting OpenLDAP Server Daemon...
runuser[110317]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by 
(uid=0)
runuser[110317]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
tlsmc_get_pin: INFO: Please note the extracted key file will not be protected 
with a PIN any more, however it will be still protected at least by file 
permissions.
tlsmc_get_pin: INFO: Please note the extracted key file will not be protected 
with a PIN any more, however it will be still protected at least by file 
permissions.
tlsmc_get_pin: INFO: Please note the extracted key file will not be protected 
with a PIN any more, however it will be still protected at least by file 
permissions.
... loop until timeout
```

Note: This happened if I installed manually as well

Might be environment issue as well because I tried in different environment it seems fine.

Anyone have any clue?